# Cannot encrypt/decrypt string using Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, encryption, kotlin

I need to encrypt string on Java, and then decrypt it on Kotlin.
I do following things:

encrypt string like that

```
private static String encrypt(String value, String password) throws NoSuchPaddingException, ... {
        final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), "AES");
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        final byte[] encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedValue);
    }
```

For decrypt in Kotlin I use this method:

```
fun String.decrypt(password: String): String {
    val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val iv = ByteArray(16)
    val charArray = password.toCharArray()
    for (i in 0 until charArray.size){
        iv[i] = charArray[i].toByte()
    }
    val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)

(1) val decryptedByteValue = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(this, Base64.DEFAULT))
    return String(decryptedByteValue)
}
```

In that case on line (1) I receive **AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed**

So, I changed it a little bit

```
fun String.decrypt(password: String): String {
    val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
(2) cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec)

    val decryptedByteValue = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(this, Base64.DEFAULT))
    return String(decryptedByteValue)
}
```

In that case in line (2) I receive **RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be specified in GCM mode**

So, after that, I changed encryption method

```
private static String encrypt(String value, String password) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), "AES");
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            iv[i] = (byte) password.toCharArray()[0];
        }
        final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    (3) cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
        final byte[] encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedValue);
    }
```

But here in line (3) I receive **java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported parameter: javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec@6d311334**

Please help me to solve this puzzle

Comment: I don't understand - the code you are trying to use to decrypt is obviously not compatible with the code you are using to encrypt.  You clearly didn't write this code yourself.  Why have you not taken the time to actually understand what this code does and research what changes you need to make?  The information to do so is readily available.

Comment: Actually, I spent some time to investigate some ways of doing this. Tried to translate (java/kotlin) and later after fail, I wrote this message. And what is obvious for you, not obvious for others. So, I think such professional like you, might write more helpful answer than you did

Comment: I'm not saying it is obvious, I'm saying that the information you need to understand the concepts required here is readily available on the internet already.  Rather than copying and pasting random code from the internet, do the research first next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing `SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")` is clearly a functionality and a security problem. AES requires a key of 16/24/32 bytes, but your password is of variable length. Never use a password as a key. Use a key derivation algorithm like PBKDF2 instead.

Regarding your error:

You are using an IvParameterSpec, however GCM does not use an IV, but a Nonce and it requires to specify the authentication tag length. Therefore you have to provide an [GCMParameterSpec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/GCMParameterSpec.html).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Now I see where to move and will continue